# Page load networking analysis

Tags: performance, google-chrome, html

[image]

I have a simple page that utilizes angular, custom fonts/icons from google, and font-awesome.

I'm trying to understand why the long gap between loading icons and font-awesome. What is the browser doing in the background that is taking that long? It couldn't possibly be angular initializing since the script hasn't even been loaded yet by the browser.

Comment: Is it the same when you disable cache?

Comment: Yeah it is the same. There will be a gap after loading either stylesheets that contain icons/fonts. I managed to improve the performance by removing the use of html templates in angular. Also, it seems like moving the font loading into the page instead of inside a main stylesheet improved the performance as well.